# Testing the internet connection is not working with Reachability

Tags: ios, reachability

I am using the updated [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) library to test whether the internet connexion is reachable. I try to Log a message in case the internet is not reachable, but the Log doesn't debug:

```
//Test the internet connection
Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    NSLog(@"Internet connexion unreachable");//Although Internet cnx is off, this message is not displayed
    return;
};

// start the notifier which will cause the reachability object to retain itself!
[reach startNotifier];
```

Am I misunderstanding the Reachability library? How to perform a given task when Internet is off? Thanx.

P.S: My iPad is only wifi, without 3G service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so best way I got is following Apple sample code:

```
   //Test the internet connection
   Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

   NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
   //See if the reachable object status is "ReachableViaWifi"
if (netStatus!=ReachableViaWiFi) {
    //If not
    NSLog(@"wifi unavailable");
    //Alert the user about the Internet cnx
    WBErrorNoticeView *notice = [WBErrorNoticeView errorNoticeInView:self.view title:@"Network Error" message:@"Check your internet connection."];
    notice.sticky = NO;
    [notice show];
    return;//Exit the method
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Alamofire to check interner, In Swift 4

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class Connectivity {

   class func isConnectedToInternet() ->Bool {
        return NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable
   }
}
```

Then call this function

```
if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet() {
    print("Yes! internet is available.")
    // do some tasks..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should register for a notification to receive changed reachibility :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
```

Look at Apple example here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_ReachabilityAppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_ReachabilityAppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_4

Comment: Hi, Thanx for your reply. Actually I found getting obliged to use `@selector` is sometimes useless. Please have a look on my answer, it works fine and do exactly what I want.